# Aptana Studio using Tomcat for Preview

Tags: tomcat, configuration, aptana, run-configuration

I've been searching for a while and couldn't find any answers for this even if many people asked. Seems I need this because of WebGL. How do you fully configure Tomcat to be use in a run configuration in Aptana ?

Now, I've set the CATALINA_HOME and Tomcat works fine by its own. Then , I've create a new server in Eclipse/Aptana . I AM NOT SURE about the document root but pretty sure about the rest of the config.

[TOMCAT CONFIG]

BASEURL : http://localhostlocal.com:8080

DOCUMENT ROOT (???): C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\test

STARTCOMMAND : C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin\startup.bat

STOPCOMMAND :C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin\shutdown.bat

[RUN CONFIGURATION] - This is the part where I am not sure.

Server section : Use selected server -> And I choose the Tomcat I've just defined.

Start Action : Tried many combination including use current page and none are working.

What should be done here to make it all work together ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's strange but I must say you are too much into specifics. Try being less specific and more general about your question, in this case.

Comment: The problem is about configuring Apache Tomcat as External Web Server for preview in Aptana / Appcelerator Studio